Adding event listeners to an api endpoint and listening to every request sent to it like a heartbeat signal
I have a FastAPI endpoint as follows
#Endpoints 
@app.post("/random_endpoint")
def random_endpoint(input_item: str) -> str: 
    # doing some work 
    # ... 
    return input_item 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # add event listeners here 
    
    # launch server 
    uvicorn.run(port=4000)
    

I want to make it so that once this endpoint is hit by the user, the logs as a response status code or if an error was encountered from it it is going to run a certain logger function that will send it to a database listening to it.
def logger(response: Dict[str, str] | Exception):
    # posts this response or exception to a database that is meant to store logging 
    pass 

I have two queries. One How do I do this? and two, what is a good database I can use that will allow me to view these logs in real time.
One thing I think I can try is use a try-catch approach.
Every time a response is generated successfully I can post a client-server interaction. If it doesn't work then I can log the error encountered which seems like a fine idea to me. It will work fine.
I also viewed this link at Stack Overflow: How do I make an event listener with decorators in Python?
Which didn't really make much sense to me, since the endpoint already has a decorator. I might be understanding it wrong.

A function can be decorated multiple times.
